# Validating Annotated ViewModel at a non Asp.Net MVC nor Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, validation

I know this question is kind odd but I got make it. I'm working in a WCF Webservice and my methods receive objects that are annotated. I want to use these annotations to validate them. I want to check is the object is valid and get it's error messages.

Below one of the objects I want to validate. I´ve been googling but all the answer I find are for asp.net mvc or web api.

```
    public class EntidadeSenior
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage="A propriedade IDSenior é de preenchimento obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage="Para a propriedade IDSenior são permitidos até 20 caracteres")]
    public string IDSenior { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="O campo nome é de preenchimento obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "Para a propriedade Nome são permitidos até 100 caracteres")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "A propriedade Status é de preenchimento obrigatório")]
    [StringLength(1, ErrorMessage = "Para a propriedade IDSenior é permitido apenas 1 caractere")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add reference to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations assembly and use Validator class from it, something like below should do the job:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public class DataAnnotationsValidator
{
    public bool TryValidate(object @object, out ICollection<ValidationResult> results)
    {
        var context = new ValidationContext(@object, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
        results = new List<ValidationResult>();

        return Validator.TryValidateObject(
            @object,
            context,
            results,
            validateAllProperties: true
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Validator.TryValidateObject:

```
EntidadeSenior yourObject;      
var context = new ValidationContext(youObject, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
                        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
                        bool valid = Validator.TryValidateObject(youObject, context, results);
```

So you can check out **valid**, and **results** returns the invalid messages based in you DataAnnotations attributes.